# IIS Certificate. Digicert tells me one thing, probing SSL / TLS another

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, jira, digital-certificate

I'm trying to get Jira service desk to pull mail from our server but im having certificate issues, I think.

When I try and pull mail from our server Jira pops up

> SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path
>   to requested target

which seems to indicate a problem with the certificate not being trusted. So went off and grabbed a new trusted cert as the old one was self certified for "ES2010" which is the name of the server.

AFAIK the new certificate has been installed but.

It seems like `*.domainname.co.uk` is where the trusted cert has been issued for is taking precident over `owa.domainname.co.uk`.

If I goto https://www.digicert.com and check out the cert it seems ok BUT if I use the Portecle app from Jira

Examine the SSL / TLS connection on port 993 (secure imap) it shows as being issued by CN=ES2010

Can anyone kindly help?

Comment: Since the error comes from Jira you need to dig into that to see what exactly is required by Jira for this certificate. Others with no Jira knowledge will not be able to provide you a proper answer.

Comment: Good news I know what the problem is now. It lies within IIS and the certificate not being installed properly.

A colleague just used OPENSSL to probe on port 993 and it's coming back with a locally issued cert.

So the cert is working for *.domainname but not *.domainname:993

Sooo I guess what Im asking for is how do I assign my cert to secure imap within IIS7